# Why does the Logic Apps Oracle connector use both 400 and 404 to express "not found"?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a number of Logic Apps which use the Oracle DB connector to retrieve data from an Oracle database via the On-Premises Data Gateway. Several of them use the Get Row action which returns a single row which it finds using the table's primary key.

On occasions when we pass an unrecognised ID, the action fails with a statusCode of *either* 400 or 404. I am certain of this and it is not a mistake. I have not seen any one Logic App flip between the two, but different Logic Apps in the same subscription and querying the same database have returned either 400 or 404.

Why does the connector flip between using two different status codes to represent the same outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that one of the tables didn't have a primary key despite our believing it did. The connector fails with 400 Bad Request if the table doesn't define a primary key, and 404 Not Found if the table is correct but the ID is not present.

The error message is particularly unhelpful in this case, but the problem is now understood.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, please check if you input the same type of row id(or other parameters) into the "Get Row" action. Most of 400 error was caused by **a type discrepancy between the passed parameter and the received parameter** or **field mismatch**. And please also check if your gateway is same to the two logic app, the gateway can also cause the 400/404 error.

If all of the configurations are same between the two logic apps, I think you can raise a support ticket on azure portal by following this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to ask azure support team for help. The answer to your question is hard to find on stack overflow.